# Getting value from query into subform using Dlookup

Tags: ms-access, dlookup

I wanna put value `Allowed` from query `S_makers_list` using Dlookup into textbox into subform C_products in HCPP form. I'm trying to use current `maker` value in subform as criteria

```
=DLookUp("[Allowed]";"S_makers_list";"[maker]= " & [me]![maker])
```

Instead of showing a value it displays `#Name` error in text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `maker` is text, you need quotes:

```
=DLookUp("[Allowed]";"S_makers_list";"[maker]='" & [me]![maker] & "'")
```